# umbraco - usercontrols - umbracoNaviHide

Tags: umbraco

I know I can get the current node with 'var top = Node.GetCurrent();' but I cant seem to find where I can get the related properties, specifically 'umbracoNaviHide'. I'd like to know how to access the same data that is accessible from XSLT in a user control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get properties you need to use the GetProperty() method.

var top = Node.GetCurrent();
top.GetProperty("umbracoNaviHide").Value;

Comment: Thanks, I had that much figured out...I had (for some reason) thought that it was a default property. After adding it, GetProperty returned it as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In Umbraco 8, you will have to do something like this:

```
    private List<NavigationListItem> GetChildNavigationList(IPublishedContent page)
    {
        List<NavigationListItem> listItems = null;
        var childPages = page.Children.Where(i => i.IsPublished());

        if (childPages != null && childPages.Any() && childPages.Count() > 0)
        {
            listItems = new List<NavigationListItem>();
            foreach (var childPage in childPages)
            {
                int myTrueFalseFieldValue = 1;
                if (childPage.HasProperty("umbracoNaviHide"))
                {
                    Int32.TryParse(childPage.GetProperty("umbracoNaviHide").GetValue().ToString(), out myTrueFalseFieldValue);
                    //myTrueFalseFieldValue = 0 // hide the page
                    //myTrueFalseFieldValue = 1 // don't hide the page
                    string name = childPage.Name;
                    int test = myTrueFalseFieldValue;
                }

                if (myTrueFalseFieldValue == 1)
                {
                    NavigationListItem listItem = new NavigationListItem(new NavigationLink(childPage.Url, childPage.Name));
                    listItem.Items = GetChildNavigationList(childPage);
                    listItems.Add(listItem);
                }
            }
        }
        return listItems;
    }
```

Above code will make sure that those pages which have set there umbrachoNaviHide checkbox property to true will not be included in the navigation list.

*In order to see how to make custom property: umbracoNaviHide, please search youtube for "Day11: Hide Pages from Navigation in Umbraco"*